# requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, timezone

What should I do with this error() since the beginning of 403 was and could not log in decided to use the agent!

```
import requests
headers = {
  'Host': 'mvideo.ru',
  'User-Agent':'Safari',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

mvideo_requests =requests.get('https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914', headers = headers)

print(mvideo_requests)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using different headers.

```
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
mvideo_requests =requests.get('https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914', headers = headers)
```